# Best software for parametric design of foldable piece with rigid and elastic parts

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I'm trying to create a parametric model of a container, using similar joints as this foldable bathtub. [image: foldable bathtub]

I do not need stress simulation, but need to see if my model can actually fold the full range of the intended motion with given parameters, or the material thickness or folding angle introduces constraints.

So my question is: are there good CAD tools for this kind of work?

Are FreeCAD or OpenSCAD good candidates?

Comment: The best tool is the one you know how to use...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have programming skills, OpenSCAD may accomplish your task. OpenSCAD allows animation, if one can perform the necessary code. The key feature of your question is "parametric" and your code should reflect that aspect.

I'm unfamiliar with FreeCAD, but there is a hobbyist version of Fusion 360, which also support parametric construction and constraints. Not so much coding, as it's primarily GUI based.

Another GUI option with parametric features is SolveSpace, multi-platform, free software, 2D-3D capable. Constraints can be created to allow movement to cover that part of your question.